# Versioning of js and css in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-cms

I have uploaded JS and CSS files under static folder by returning below from `settings.py`:

```
return os.path.join(get_valid_filename(filename))
```

I want to know how can I update the same CSS and js file

Answer (score 0):

If u have defined your `staticfiles_dirs` and `static_url`, you can simply run `python manage.py collectstatic` after the changes have been made, assuming I am understanding the question